# Request remote notification outside AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have an onboarding viewcontroller, where the user can click a button "allow notifications" and then the request alert for push notifications show up.

I have done so:
**OnboardingViewController**

```
onboardingViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

func registerForRemoteNotification() {
        
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil && granted {
                print("Brugeren har accepteret notifikationer")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
            
        }
        
}
```

The issue is that this function in AppDelegate is not called, when I do it like the above example:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    print("Test 1")
         
    completionHandler()
}
```

The "didReceive" function will only be called, if I put the `requestAuthorization` code inside the AppDelegate file, inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

How do you guys fix this issue?

Comment: You're setting the delegate to `self` -- you should be setting it to the `AppDelegate`. Note also that this needs to happen early in the lifecycle. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649522-delegate

Comment: @jnpdx if I set it to ```AppDelegate``` I get this error: ```Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate.Type' to type '(any UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate)?'```

Comment: Did you declare your AppDelegate as `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` compliant? Then, how did you try to set the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate`? Should be something llke `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate`?

Comment: @Larme that did it, I just set it to ```= AppDelegate``` did not know I had to do the ```UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate``` part - thank you guys!

Comment: `AppDelegate` is the name of the class, that's not an object. It's like saying "Banana", but it's not "a banana", it's just the name of the fruit, not a specific banana.

Comment: @Larme makes sense. Thank you! Do you know why the ```didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken``` function is not called?

Comment: @Larme the ```didReceive``` function is only called, the time when the user accepts the notifications. If I then close the app and launch simulator again, then it is not called upon receiving notifications :(

Comment: @M.Holm read the documentation that I linked to about when to set the delegate.

Comment: @jnpdx makes sense now - I just added the ```delegate``` to the ```didFinishLaunchingWith``` function and now the ```didReceive``` works all the time - thank you! But the ```didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken``` does not get called at all :(

Comment: Are you sure you have the signature correct?

Comment: @jnpdx did a stupid mistake. You can only get a deviceToken on a real device, I was in the simulator. Thank you guys for your help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: The other thing to remember is that there is a difference between *registering* for notifications and *sending* notifications. You should always *register* for notifications and establish your delegate in `didFinishLaunching`. This is because the push token *can change* so you need to be prepared to capture this new value and update your back end. Later you can ask if the user wants notifications; if they say "yes" then ask for local notification permissions and update your backend to indicate that notifications should be sent to this user (or always send notifications)

Comment: If you always send notifications then the user controls with settings whether they are actually displayed